# Gradient of solution to heat equation under evolving metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-analysis, ricci-flow

The following simple question came to me when I was studying the heat equation on a Riemannian manifold: Suppose $M$ is a closed Riemannian manifold and $g_t$ is a smooth family of Riemannian metrics on $M$. It's a well-known question the study the evolving heat equation on $M$:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}f=\Delta_{g(t)} f
\end{equation}
Suppose that $V\subset TM$ is a fixed sub-bundle of the tangent space of $M$. Given that at time $t=0$, the gradient of $f_0$ belongs to $V$. Is it true that the gradient of $f$ remains in $V$ the whole time? I have a feeling that this is true because of the equalizing nature of the heat equation, but I don't know how to formally prove or disprove it. Does anyone have any thoughts or helpful references?
Please apologize if this is a trivial matter.

Comment: In general, this will not be the case. To see this, let $M$ be Euclidean  space, $f$ be arbitrary but have no critical points and consider the one-dimensional sub-bundle generated by $\nabla f$ when the metric is fixed. This isn't exactly a counterexample because Euclidean space is not compact, but it shows that you need to make stronger assumptions to show something like this.

Comment: In the context of Ricci flow, if $f$ is invariant under a class of isometries at the initial time, then its heat flow will remain so for positive times as well. As such, it is possible to get a statement like this but under a stronger assumption.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, Ricci flow is exactly the case I'm referring to in this question. May you be a little bit more specific about what kind of stronger conditions might be imposed here?

Answer (score 3):

Let me expand a bit on my comment to try to answer your question.

In general, there is no relationship between the metrics $g(t)$ and the sub-bundle $V$, so it is possible to find examples where the gradient is contained in $V$ at an initial time but is not contained within it for future times.

To get a positive answer, we need to assume that the sub-bundle $V$ interacts with the metric in a nice way. For instance, if $V$ is the tangent bundle of a totally geodesic foliation of $M$, then it might be possible to show that $\nabla f \subset V$ is preserved if you deform the metric by Ricci flow and the function by a heat equation. To be honest though, I don't know if this is the case or not. However, there is one situation where the answer is affirmative.

Consider the case where the function $f$ is invariant under the action of some group of isometries $G$. At first, this might seem unrelated to sub-bundles, but the idea is that when the group is infinite, this condition implies that the $\nabla f$ must be perpendicular to the infinitesimal transformations induced by the isometries (picture $O(1)$ spinning a round $\mathbb{S}^2$ around its axis and $f$ only a function of the polar angle). The subset of $TM$ perpendicular to the infinitesimal transformations is not necessarily a bundle (as can be seen with this example), but $f(t)$ will remain invariant under the group action under Ricci flow (so $\nabla f$ remains in a subset of $TM$).

To see this, we use the uniqueness of the Ricci flow. For compact manifolds, this was proven by Hamilton and for complete manifolds with bounded curvature, Ricci flow uniqueness is a theorem of Chen-Zhu [1]. These results imply that the isometries at the initial time are preserved in forward time, and when combined with the linearity of the heat equation, it follows that $f(t)$ is preserved under $G$ for positive time as well.

Since you are asking this question about Ricci flow, I'm guessing that you might be interested in the case where the heat flow runs in *reverse time* (since that's how the $\mathcal{W}$-functional is defined). In this case, the flow \begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}f=\Delta_{g(t)} f
\end{equation} no longer preserves mass so you need an extra term to correct for that. After fixing that issue, you can use the same argument as before to show that $f$ remains invariant under the group $G$, except now we use Kotschwar's result showing backwards uniqueness for the Ricci flow [2].

[1] *Chen, Binglong; Zhu, Xiping*, [**Uniqueness of the Ricci flow on complete noncompact manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1175266184), J. Differ. Geom. 74, No. 1, 119-154 (2006). [ZBL1104.53032](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1104.53032).

[2] *Kotschwar, Brett L.*, [**Backwards uniqueness for the Ricci flow**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/imrn/rnq022), Int. Math. Res. Not. 2010, No. 21, 4064-4097 (2010). [ZBL1211.53086](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1211.53086).

Comment: Dear Gabe, thanks so much for your detailed answer. Exactly, my concern now is the case that you pointed out when V is a sub-bundle of a totally geodesics foliation on M. I have a feeling that Ricci flow and heat equation will preserve that fact that gradient of f stays inside V (i.e. being vertical), however I cant comment more since I'm not so familiar with it. If you have any further thoughts, please let me know. Appreciated!

Comment: My approach now is to consider the restriction of $f$ to each leaf, then evolve it under heat equation with respect to the metric induced from the ambient space $M$. The fact that $\nabla f$ stay in $V$ just means that the Laplacian of $f$ with respect the the metric on $M$ equals to the Laplacian of the restriction of $f$ to each leaf with respect to the induced metric on that leaf.